# Combing array of datetime slots to sot with specific duration

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I am trying to find all available slots with a specific duration (in this case 20 minutes) from an array of exisiting slots, except that they are in 10 minute intervals.

The end result would be an array with two slots of 09:00:00 - 09:20:00 and 09:40:00 to 10:00:00

Any ideas on the PHP function I could use to check and combine these?

```
Array (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [slot_start] => 2017-09-27 09:00:00
                [slot_end] => 2017-09-27 09:10:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [slot_start] => 2017-09-27 09:10:00
                [slot_end] => 2017-09-27 09:20:00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [slot_start] => 2017-09-27 09:20:00
                [slot_end] => 2017-09-27 09:30:00
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [slot_start] => 2017-09-27 09:40:00
                [slot_end] => 2017-09-27 09:50:00
            )
       [4] => Array
            (
                [slot_start] => 2017-09-27 09:50:00
                [slot_end] => 2017-09-27 10:00:00
            )


    )
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Thanks John, just wondering if someone can point me to specific functions that will help me write the code, not write the code for me :)

Comment: Still not okay for this website. We don't point users to documentation to recommend libraries or existing code. We answer *specific questions* about *code you've written*. See the links I provided above to see how this site works.

Comment: No problems, thanks